# The form of a series

Tags: calculus

I have a problem with series.
Consider a series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k.$$ Can I rewrite it as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}\  ?$$  Or more generally, can I rewrite it as 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{\sigma_k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{\delta_k},$$ where $\sigma,\delta$ is the selection of $k$?
I'm considering the proof
$$S_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k},$$ then get the limit when $n\to \infty$, but I don't think it is right.

Comment: Not always. Consider $1-1+1-1+1-\cdots$.

Comment: If your series is conditionally convergent you cannot just rearrange terms like that.

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, I know what you mean.Does that mean if the series is not absolutely convergent, you  can't write it like that

Comment: @Ginjerjin: Do your two series (evens and odds) converge individually?  If the answer is yes, then there is no problem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No, I don't assume it. I'm wondering if the odd is convergent while the even is not.Can I write it like that?

Comment: @Gingerjin: If one of them converges while the other does not, then the full sum (everybody) does not converge. Then you can sort of write it like that, but neither $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ nor $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}$ converges, so it is not useful.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Actually, I want to ask is that whether the original series is convergent, will the rewritten form change the property of the original form,such as convergence or the value.

Comment: @Take $a_k=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$. Then $\sum a_k$ is convergent, but sum of evens, sum of odds are both divergent.

Comment: \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty does not look the same as \sum_{n=1}^\infty.  The latter is standard.  In a "displayed" setting the latter makes the subscript and superscript appear below and above the \sum; the former fails to do that: $\displaystyle \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty$ versus $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty$.  Even in an "inline", as opposed to "displayed", setting, there's a difference: $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty$ versus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$.  I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general: If you have two *convergent* series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k \quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k.
$$
Then the series 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(b_k + c_k)
$$
is also convergent. So for example if $b_k$ and $c_k$ are given by $b_k = a_{2k-1}$ and $c_k = a{2k}$, then indeed you get a convergent series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k-1} + a_{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k.
$$
Note that for this to be true, you do not need anything to be *absolutely* convergent.

Now if you rearrange the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ so that as $k$ varies in $\mathbb{N}$ then $\delta_k$ also varies through $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. $\delta : k \mapsto \delta_k$ is a bijection, then in general it is not true that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{\delta_k}
$$
even if the series is convergent. But if the series is *absolutely* convergent, then this is true.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already noticed, the series must be absolutely convergent for this to be true. To see even better that all hell breaks loose when the series is only conditionally convergent, consider [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem): if $\sum a_n$ is a conditionally convergent series, then for *every* real number $x$, (or even $x=\pm\infty$) there is a permutation $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{\sigma(n)} = x$.

Comment: All the answers say that I rearrange the terms. But i can't figure out how $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k=\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{2k-1}+\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{2k}$ rearrange the original term. Can you help me

Comment: Because it's as if you summed first the even terms, then the odd terms (or the other way). You can't actually do that with a permutation of $\mathbb N$ (putting all the even terms then all the odd terms), but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,it can write as that,because $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k}$, when $n \to \infty$,

then we have

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}$, **if when $n \to \infty$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}$ exist**.

**note**: If $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ converges, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$,this is definition of series. But if when $n \to \infty$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}$ are not all exist. You can not write as that.

Comment: I think your definition $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ may not be right. Actually the series may not converge.

Comment: @KannappanSampath I think you should read through his answer.

Comment: @Gingerjin Right, I missed that.

Comment: @Gingerjin thanks,correct it.